# Pointer set to NULL when passed to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree, null

I have a C++ class named `BET`. It is a class for a binary expression tree. Here are the relevant functions and member data:

```
class BET{
  ....
  private:
    struct BinaryNode {
      string element;
      BinaryNode *left;
      BinaryNode *right;
      BinaryNode(const string &e, BinaryNode *l = NULL, BinaryNode *r = NULL) : element(e), left(l), right(r) {}
    };
    BinaryNode *root;
    BinaryNode * clone(BinaryNode *t) const;
};

const BET & BET::operator=(const BET &rhs) {
  (*this).root = clone(rhs.root);
  return *this;
}
....
BET::BinaryNode * BET::clone(BinaryNode *t) const {
  if(t == NULL) {
    return new BinaryNode(NULL);
  }
  BinaryNode * temp = new BinaryNode(t->element);
  temp->left = clone(t->left);
  temp->right = clone(t->right);
  return temp;
}
```

I am running into a situation where `clone()` always returns a NULL `BinaryNode` because the `rhs.root` pointer is set to 0 when passed. I have verified `rhs.root` is a valid address in `operator=()`.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Why not post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It does compile. The error comes when I do `BET bet3; bet3 = bet1;`

Comment: @songyuanyao [It compiled](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/D4fBNTyoZYINs0oQ) after adding declaration of `operator=`. non-const member function cannot be called from const member function, but const member function can be called from non-const member function.

Comment: @user1710563  This code is invalid if(t == NULL) {
    return new BinaryNode(NULL);
  } should be at least if(t == NULL) return NULL;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why?

Comment: @Amadeus Is not the method called clone?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah, understood

Comment: @user1710563  In any case the operator is wrong because it does not delete current nodes of the tree